# how to compare two range time for find duplicates records in sql

Tags: php, sql

how to compare two range time for find duplicates records in sql .

Example :-

```
time_start   time_end

1000         1400

1200         1400
```

above 1200 to 1400 repeat duplicates time

please help me.

Comment: can you give an example output, what difference are you looking at? i assume hours?

Comment: Please include what you've already tried.

Comment: I'm not sure "duplicate" is the right word here. I *think* you mean "overlapping" time ranges, which is a bit harder to do.

Comment: what is the datatype of those columns? is it `varchar(4)` or `int`?

Comment: Overlap with this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6571538/checking-a-table-for-time-overlap

Answer (score 0):

This will get you the difference between the two dates

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(hh,time_start,time_end)
```

This will group the duplicates and give you a count

```
SELECT 
    DATEDIFF(hh,time_start,time_end) AS Diff,
    COUNT(*) AS DuplicateCount
FROM 
    table
DATEDIFF(hh,time_start,time_end)
```

Comment: You might want to mention that this is mysql specific.

Comment: It will show how many of the record has same difference in `time_start` and `time_end`.

Answer (score 0):

you have to fixed the start time as static and end time common.

use this code:

select * from table_name where time_start >= 1200 and time_end <= 1400;