# Two times between in two columns sql

Tags: mysql, sql, time

I have record of fromtime and endtime in database table. There is fromtime= 09:00 and endtime = 10:00 so add a new fromtime= 09:05 and endtime= 10:05 then system will b show alert message that both times already exists.

I am using this sql statement

```
SELECT * 
FROM `tbl_timetable` 
WHERE fromtime <= '09:05' AND totime >= '10:05'
```

but cannot get any alert message of both times already exists.

[image: Table image]

Comment: Well, you're asking for a record where `totime` is greater than or equal to `10:05`, and `10:00` obviously does not match that criterion.

Comment: yup does not match but is there any query condition which match between 09:00 and 10:00

Comment: I guess you want to find overlapping time ranges? If so, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6571538/checking-a-table-for-time-overlap

Comment: Yes, change `totime >= '10:00'` :S

Comment: @sagi but user want to add this fromtime=09:05 and endtime= 10:05 then how to stop the user to add

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query should be:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tbl_timetable
WHERE '10:05' > fromtime AND totime > '09:05'
```

[Tests on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b4ac23dac623bd2fe21860133838e6ec)